R's NA_REAL conversion to integer in C++ now gives 0 on Mac (instead of NA_INTEGER)
Reprex:
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int dbl2int(double x) { return x; }

/*** R
dbl2int(NA_real_)
*/


Rcpp::sourceCpp("test-dbl2int.cpp")

On Mac, it outputs 0, while it outputs NA_INTEGER on Windows and Linux (cf. https://github.com/privefl/testbigstatsr/actions/runs/10737751205/job/29779881355#step:6:165).
Note: this issue appeared only recently on Mac (it has given NA_INTEGER for years..).
Any idea what's going on, and how to do this conversion so that it works for all platforms and is still efficient?

Edit: It seems that Inf is now converted to 2147483647 instead of NA_INTEGER; but -Inf is still converted to NA..

Not sure of the technical details but suspect it has something to do with int overflow. Probably best to use something safer like return 'return x != x ? NA_INTEGER : x'

Yes, this seems to work.

This may well be risky code. You are relying an a very non-standard NA conversion: only R knows about NA for integer, so you are betting on the appropriate R conversion being found.  I am not sure we can rely on that.
Two things come to mind.  First, maybe see if you can distill this into a pure C API for R function and then report to r-devel. (Also, if and when that works and this does not, file an Rcpp bug showing that.)
Second, use a safer converter.  Something like
Rcpp::cppFunction("int dbl2int(double x) { 
     if (ISNAN(x)) return NA_INTEGER; else return static_cast<int>(x); }")

You can also test via R_IsNA(), there is a bit of overlap between test predicates.

Yes, this would be safer, but I think R_IsNA() slows down the conversion by a lot (from what I remember).

So now you can trade-off between "epsilon slower but it works" and "fast but wrong". Isn't engineering great?  :

IIRC, it was 3-4 times slower.

Note that they also changed the conversion from +Inf to int..
